# Is there a way to always show the 'hover' effect of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a table that has hover effects associated with it. I'm just wondering how I could have the first table row display its hover effect all the time.

I tried hunting down a way to do this but couldn't find anything on the matter.

Comment: You'll need to post your code.

Comment: Use the `first-child` and `last` psuedo css selectors and just set the style

Comment: Just style the non-hovered state the same as the hovered state.